# DB compression with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: compression, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

In SQL Server 2008 R2, at the time of backup there is 3 modes available under compression field

1. Use the default server setting
2. Compress Backup
3. Do not Compress Backup

Here I have a question that when we take backup by choosing the option `Compress Backup`, so it will affect any kind of data loss or performance issue with the DB or it is same as to choose `Do not Compress Backup` or `Use the default server setting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since most systems are I/O-bound and not CPU-bound, the backup will almost always complete faster (and will always take up less disk space, unless the data is already highly compressed or non-compressible) with compression on. It will also be more portable since a smaller file is more network-friendly.

I have never heard of any instances of data loss or performance loss when using compression. The only exception would be a system that has no I/O constraints at all but is already highly CPU-bound (since compression trades off some I/O cost for CPU cycles).

Comment: so it means it will not affect db data in general ?

Comment: @Rikky it compresses data, it doesn't delete it.